# Is it common to add noise to Time Series data before training a model

Tags: time-series

I once read about somebody who added noise to their time series before training a model. They didn't write why they did it though.

Is this common practice?

If it is, why do people do it ie. to prevent over-fitting?

Comment: Could you link the source? Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the source for it. It was something I read about a long time ago and didn't bookmark it.

Comment: Was it a rigorous work? Like an academic-level paper, or a highly specialized blog? Or was it something less reliable? (Just out of curiosity)

Comment: It was something less reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go through your questions one by one:

> I once read about somebody who added noise to their time series before training a model. They didn't write why they did it though.

No, noise is not adding any value to your dataset. The reason is that noise, by definition, cannot be learned by any statistical/ML model.

---

> Is this common practice?

No it's not.

---

> why do people do it ie. to prevent over-fitting?

It's not a technique that helps you in preventing overfitting. There are several techniques to do it (ensemble modeling, cross validation), many of them depend on the kind of model you want to implement (such as recurrent dropout for RNNs).

Comment: Thanks. If there any particular reason why one would want to add noise to a time-series?

Comment: Perhaps if you want to create some toy dataset and test some simulations? But I can't find rigorous, *scientific* reasons.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for the help.